# Hit Detection Implementation in Processing.JS

Tags: processing.js

I am having some trouble with programming hit detection in Processing.JS. I have tried to make a function that checks if something is touching an object and returns true and otherwise returns false. This is that here.

`Snake.prototype.checkTouching = function(v){
    if(v.position.x > this.position.x - this.width/2 && v.position < this.position.x + this.width/2 && v.position.y > this.positon.y - this.height/2 && v.position.y < this.position.y + this.height/2){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
};`
  I am implementing it by creating a new variable "b" in my draw function that holds the value the function returned then using an if statement to check if the value "b" is holding is true. Like so

```
  var b = snakey.checkTouching(mos);
var restarts = 0;
if(b === true){
    restarts += 1;
    Program.restart();
}
```

unfortunately even when the object the function is running on is touching the object that is running it nothing happens. I have already checked to see if the logic works and it is valid so I know it has to be my implementation I just can not seem to find out what is wrong with my implementation. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? Full program here.[Full Program](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-project-creature-colonies/6085454506295296)

Comment: Can you please debug your program to see exactly where it behaves differently from what you expect? For starters, what is the `checkTouching()` function actually returning? If you still can't get it figured out, please post a [mcve] directly in the post. Note that this should not be your whole project, but should be just enough code for us to run to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Kevin Workman I debuged every way I know how  and for some reason the    checkTouching()    function is never returning true, but I know of no reason for it to not to as I have tested this very same logic apart from the rest of the program and it works.

Comment: Are you sure the `checkTouching()` function is being called? What is the value of the `v` parameter? You need to step through your program until you understand exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: Kevin Workman yes it is definitely being called as I am getting a return from it it is just that it is always coming back false. And yes I know what it is using and yes I know what the value of the v parameter is. I know how to look for problems in a program and I understand what everything is doing. I have gone over all the code several times though so I must be missing something. That is why I brought my problem here.

Comment: The problem is, we can't really help you because we can't run this code. We have no way of knowing what the value of `v` is. That's why I'm asking for a [mcve], so we can help you debug your program. Without it, the best I can do is try to ask you questions to help you debug it yourself- if you know the value of `v`, then you should be able to figure out exactly what the `if` statement is doing. Which part of it is evaluating to false?

Comment: Here, this is as minimal as I can make it without removing things that might be affecting the results of my if statement. https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/new/pjs